# How is a pgfplotstable table stored internally?

Tags: pgfplotstable

I'm writing some `lua` code that outputs a table saved to a file that is then read by `\pgfplotstableread{myfile.dat}\mytable`. I'd like to avoid two steps: saving to a file and reading with `\pgfplotstableread`. So, my option is to "write" directly `\mytable` on `lua` side. But I don't know how tables are stored internally by `pgfplotstable`. I did some experiment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Name, Age, stDev
Adam, 15, 3
Eve, 12, 1
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\show\mytable

\end{document}
```

This results in:

```
> \mytable=macro:
->\pgfpl@@ {Name}\pgfpl@@ {Age}\pgfpl@@ {stDev}.
```

So I guess the other lines are stored in other macros. My question is how?

Comment: Check out `\pgfplotstablegetelem{⟨row⟩}{⟨col⟩}\of⟨table⟩`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the comments in `pgfplotstableshared.code.tex` (line 31-53)

> ```
> % This file provides a high-level table manipulation and typesetting
> % package.
> %
> %
> % ---------------------------------------------
> %  Implementation notes for programmers:
> % ---------------------------------------------
> %
> %  The table data structure consists of
> %  1. A name which must be a valid TeX macro like '\table'
> %  2. A column list in the \pgfplotslist format.
> %   In fact, the column list is stored in the table's name:
> %     \pgfplotslistnewempty\table
> %  3. A "file name" stored in
> %     \csname\string<\namemacro>@@table@name\endcsname
> %  4. A "scan line length" number stored in
> %         \csname\string<\namemacro>@@table@scanline\endcsname
> %         It contains the value of \pgfplotsscanlinelength which has
> %         been identified right after \pgfplotstableread.
> %  5. foreach column, there is a list of row-values (a row-vector) in
> %  the \pgfplotslist format named
> %         \csname\string<\namemacro>@<column name>\endcsname
> %
> ```

we can write the following test

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
Name, Age, stDev
Adam, 15, 3
Eve, 12, 1
}\mytable

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}\makeatletter\ttfamily

\item[2] \string\mytable \\
\meaning\mytable

\item[3] file name \\
\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\mytable @@table@name\endcsname

\item[4] scan line length \\
\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\mytable @@table@scanline\endcsname

\item[5] column Name \\
\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\mytable @Name\endcsname

\item[5] column Age \\
\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\mytable @Age\endcsname

\item[5] column stDev \\
\expandafter\meaning\csname\string\mytable @stDev\endcsname

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This gives us
[image]